# lmgrd does not work on Ubuntu 23.04

Tags: ubuntu, lsb

When I'm trying to run `lmgrd` it shows the follwing:

```
lmgrd: cannot execute: required file not found
```

Searching on the Internet I found out that it requires LSB (linux standard base) package support. But at the same time I found out that Ubuntu 23.04 doesn't support LSB anymore.

How am I supposed to run `lmgrd` now? Is there a way to work this around?